# Adjust weighting on propensity score matching in Stata

Tags: stata, matching

I am trying to create a comparison group of observations using propensity score matching. There are some characteristics that I care more about matching on than others. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to adjust the relative weights of variables I'm matching on when constructing the propensity score?
2. If so, how would one do this in Stata (with the psmatch2 command, for example)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [coarsened exact matching](https://gking.harvard.edu/cem). There's a user-written command called `cem` that implements this in Stata and several other packages.

However, this is not equivalent to PSM, where the scores are estimated rather than imposed by the analyst.